# Session destroy automatically in laravel 5.1 with angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

**Session is destroy automatically** in **laravel 5.1.**

I am using laravel for server side and angularjs for client side.

I am using laravel session and for front end keep session data in root scope and window Storage. My application working fine but some times randomly session destroy.

i am facing problem of session automatic session destroy.

can you please help me for solve this problem ? what i missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have provided no code at all, no error messages(if any). Any answer you receive is pure speculation and thus irrelevant for the question at hand. Please review your question.

Comment: I have use laravel session and for front end keep session data in root scope and window Storage. My application working fine but some times randomly session destroy.

Comment: That doesn't help at all. It could be a million reasons. From literal failure to write to the disk or some variable that is not set properly. Check logs, post code, what you're currently offering does not help. At all. I could just as well get a crystal ball and make some random prediction.

Comment: On a standard project, you normally store user's session in the file or database and use cookie for storing session id on a client side. This doesn't seem to be the case in your project. If you don't know which chunk of code to put here, may be you can elaborate around the module/plugin you use on the front-end. Also let us know how you handle the session on backend. You don't use JWT, do you?

Comment: Finally I have solution for this issue. This is due to session file read write issue. Now I have use database driver for storing session and my problem fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have solution for this issue. This is due to session driver file type when multiple request call in angularjs file read/write not properly. cause of this token missmatch error and session destroy. Now I have use database driver for storing session and my problem fixed